# CakePHP and PHP 5.4 Strict Warnings

Tags: php, cakephp, warnings, strict, php-5.4

There are some other questions made, but no answer was specific for CakePHP, so I'm making a new one and giving the answer as well:

How to shoot down Strict Warnings in Cake PHP?

Simple, just add the code "& ~E_STRICT" in the line "level" in /App/Config/core.php

```
    Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
    'trace' => true
));
```

This practice is not very recommended, it is always better to keep strict. But there may be some cases you need to. For example I'm working in a new release of my app in the same server were the old one is. I'm not wasting time correcting errors in the old app. Jus keep strict in the new code. Other case is when you have a live app and you need some time to correct this kind of errors.

I hope this is useful for new CakePHP programmers.

Comment: Adding questions and answer is very welcome, but it is recommended to add the answer as an actual answer and mark it as accepted (just in case you're not aware http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That being said, I think if possible the preferred option should be to keep the core updated and write strict code. You might want to add that to your answer, and point out that masking errors like that should only be done in legacy applications where you have to stick to older code.

Comment: @ndm Sorry I wasn't aware of the self-answer policy. And I'm Agree with you, there are some cases where you really need to shoot down strict warnings.